# Multiply two polynomials without using convolution

Tags: matlab

I know that I should use nested for loops. Say two polynomials are x and y. (both are vectors)
But in the end I only get the coefficients of every term after multiplying - `x(i)*y(j)`

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking "what's an alternative to convolution?"?

Comment: I know I can just use conv(p1,p2) to get the product of two polynomials. But I need to write a function which takes in two vectors(two polynomials) and the output should be the product of the two polynomials.

Comment: So write your own convolution!  See the "definitions" section of http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/conv.html, or take a look at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution.

Comment: But that is how you multiply polynomials.

Comment: Yup. But my professor said we couldn't use convolution.

Comment: Do it the same way you were taught how to multiply polynomials in middle school?

Comment: @Mysticial: That *is* convolution (assuming we're thinking about the same method).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Then we probably have different definitions. I use the term convolution only if it involves an FFT. But that's probably just me and my professor.

Comment: @Mysticial: I tend to use the conventional definition of convolution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Comment: i figured it out. thanks for help guys

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply the polynomials without *doing* a convolution,
this is what the [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFT) does.
Matlab has an [`fft`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fft.html) function.

If you want to multiply the polynomials without using the built-in convolution function, use `for` loops to implement the algorithm you learned in middle school.

Comment: @Mysticial It does give you the outcome of a convolution. But if you count that there's absolutely no way to do this problem without "using a convolution", because "multiplying polynomials" means "give me the output of a convolution".